# Proper way of Navigation in SwiftUI after async task

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have screen with `List` of Views one of them is `NavigationLink` that navigates to separate screen `DocumentPreviewView` where PDF document is presented.

This PDF document need to be downloaded asynchronously on the first screen after button is tapped and need to be passed to the `DocumentPreviewView` screen.

**I came to working solution but I' m looking for more elegant way and more SwiftUI way.
Maybe document should be some kind of observable object.**

This is my current solution. As you can see I use hidden NavigationLink that is being triggered by callback from button action where I also download document which I need to present.

```
@State private var document = PDFDocument()
@State private var docState: DocState? = .setup

enum DocState: Int {
    case setup = 0
    case ready = 1
}

var body: some View {
    List {
    /// some other views

        Button(action: {
            someAsyncFunction { doc, error in 
              self.document = doc
              self.docState = .ready
            }
          }) {
          Text("Show Document")
        }

    /// some other views
    }

    NavigationLink(
            destination: DocumentPreviewView(pdfDocument: document), 
            tag: .ready, 
            selection: $docState) {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

Comment: There might be several approaches, you use one of them, so it is rather opinion-based.

Comment: @Asperi for me the strangest part of this solution that I am using hidden UI component, looks more like workaround rather than elegant solution

Comment: From a UX point of view I would recommend navigating to the new screen as soon as the user interacts with your app and show a spinner or loading bar while you're downloading the PDF.

Comment: @moonvader No, it is widely used pattern to activate navigation programmatically. Just search here NavigationLink+EmptyView and you find tons of use-cases for it.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var docState: DocState? = .setup
    
    enum DocState: Int {
        case setup = 0
        case ready = 1
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("Preview"),
                    tag: .ready,
                    selection: $docState) {
                    Button(action: {
                        someTask() { isTaskDone in
                            docState = .ready
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("Download")
                    }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func someTask(_ completion: @escaping ((Bool)->())) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            completion(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How document should be passed in this case? I think I already tried this approach but there was problem with passing the document